# reservation/waiting list wicked algorithm php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble designing the algorithm for a reservation type system with a waiting list.

There can 3 active slots at any given time and each last for one month, and after that they are put on a waiting list. I want to be able to insert the date when the item will move from waiting to active status.

I know the three dates that are active ($date1, $date2, $date3) and can retrieve them easily.

What I need is a function that will calculate the activation date each time it is called based on the following pattern:

Ideally the start date column on the waiting list table would look like this:

1. $date1
2. $date2
3. $date3
4. $date1 + 1 month
5. $date2 + 1 month
6. $date3 + 1 month
7. $date1 + 2 months
8. $date2 + 2 months
9. $date3 + 2 months
10. $date1 + 3 months
11. $date2 + 3 months
12. $date3 + 3 months
13. $date1 + 4 months etc..

Any help/ideas would be GREATLY appreciated - I'm totally stuck!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)

```
$nextMonth = strtotime('+1 month', $unixTimeStampOfDate);

// or to create a list
$dates = array(strtotime('2014-03-21'), strtotime('2014-03-25'), strtotime('2014-03-30')); 
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    foreach($dates as $date) {
        echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+' . $i . ' month', $date)); 
        echo '<br/>'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too worried about the time calculation, what I cant figure out is how to structure the method so it gives me the above structure. Thanks though!